# How to cross-reference an inequality with \cref?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I have inequalities being cross-referenced by `\cref` as equations.

1-) How can I change that? (and still have inequalities with the same numbering as equations)

2-) How can I change that and have inequalities with their own numbering?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
&f(x) \geq g(x)& \label{i:positivity}
\end{flalign}

Admitting that \cref{i:positivity} has a solution, ...  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not use `\eqref{}`?

Comment: This solves. But since I was using `cref` to automatically handle all the different types of references, I was wondering if this would still be doable using it.

Comment: @Sigur - Assume the `hyperref` package is loaded and `cleveref` was loaded with the option `nameinlink`. By writing "`by inequality \eqref{xyz}`" instead of "`by \cref{xyz}`", one loses the feature of having the word "inequality" be part of the "target" of the hyperlink.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you want to use the same counter variable for both equation-like and inequality-like environments, you can proceed by informing `cleveref` (i) that certain environments are "special" (specifically, that they are inequalities) and (ii) what to do in terms of typesetting the cross-references to these "special" objects. The former can be achieved by providing an optional argument to the `\label` command. (`cleveref` cleverly redefines `\label` to make this possible.) The latter can be achieved by executing appropriate `\crefname` and `\creflabelformat` instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} %%  just for this example

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} 
\crefname{ineq}{inequality}{inequalities}
\creflabelformat{ineq}{#2{\upshape(#1)}#3} 
 %% \upshape ensures that the number and surrounding parens are typeset in upright mode

\setlength\parindent{0pt} %%  just for this example
\setlength\textwidth{4in} %%  just for this example

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
&f(x) \geq g(x)& \label[ineq]{i:positivity} %% note optional argument of \label
\end{flalign}
Admitting that \cref{i:positivity} has a solution, \dots 
\end{document}
```

Section 6 of the user guide of the `cleveref` package provides a fuller explanation of how this works. In that section, it's also explained how to automate this a bit if you have lots and lots of inequalities, in which case it might become tedious to have to remember to supply the option `ineq` to `\label` whenever the object is an inequality.

Comment: Did you mean to write either `\textup{(#1)}` or `{\upshape(#1)}` where you used `\upshape{(#1)}`?

Comment: @Crissov - Good catch: It should be `{\upshape(1)}`. I'll edit the code accordingly.

Comment: The 10th upvote on this answer not only awarded me a "good answer" bronze badge, but badge #1,500 overall on this site! Many thanks!!

Comment: Why is `{\upshape(#1)}` preferable to `\textup{(#1)}`?

Comment: @EvanAad - I don't think that I claimed that `{\upshape(#1)}` was preferable to `\textup{(#1)}`. User Crissov pointed out that `\upshape{(#1)}` was wrong and gave me two alternatives, both of which are corrrect. I'm guessing that since the code already contained `\upshape`, it was less editing work for me to choose `{\upshape(#1)}` than `\textup{(#1)}`. To be honest, though, since this episode occurred more than 8 years ago, I'm not really sure now what exactly my thought process was at the time.