# Overriding noun used by cleverref

Tags: cleveref

I have a certain set of equations in my document which I would prefer cleverref to reference using a different noun. That is, for some equations I would like cleverref to reference those equations as usual, e.g., Equation 1. However, for a specific set of equations I would like cleverref to reference them as Rule 1.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\tag{I-EQ}
    \label{eq:1}
    a + b
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:2}
    c + d
\end{equation}

Reference \Cref{eq:1}.
Reference \Cref{eq:2}.

\end{document}
```

In the above example, I would like `eq:1` to be referenced as 'Rule  (I-EQ)', while `eq:2` continues to be referenced as 'Equation 1'.

Comment: Does the posting [How to reference an inequality with \cref?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/190983/5001) help? (Just replace the word "inequality" with "rule"...)

Comment: That did help! Thank you!

Comment: Glad the suggestion was useful. I've gone ahead and voted to close this posting as a duplicate of the earlier query.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.