# How to create a new equation-like environment?

Tags: equations, environments, cleveref

The following LaTeX code was saved in `~\Test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{q}
x \leq y
\end{equation}
Behold~\cref{q}. 
\end{document}
```

Then the following commands were executed in the Terminal.

```
> cd ~
> lualatex Test
```

Consequently a PDF file was generated in `~\Test.pdf`. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displayed as follows. (I screencaptured only the relevant part of the display.)

[image: Equality environment]

I would like to create an `equality`-like environment named `inequality`, which will be used to typeset inequalities, and whose cross-reference will read *ineq.* instead of *eq.* . The effect of this new feature should be such that if in the above LaTeX code the two occurrences of `equality` are replaced by `inequality`, the resulting PDF file will be almost the same as before, except that the abbreviation *eq.* will be replaced by *ineq.*. The new `inequality` environment should share a counter with the `equality` environment.

---

**An attempt**

I tried carrying out my goal using the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newenvironment{inequality}{\begin{equation}}{\end{equation}}
\crefname{inequality}{ineq.}{ineqs.}
\Crefname{inequality}{Ineq.}{Ineqs.}
\begin{document}
\begin{inequality}\label{q}
x \leq y
\end{inequality}
Behold~\cref{q}. 
\end{document}
```

However, the resulting PDF file looked the same as before. In particular the cross-reference was written as *eq.*, and not as *ineq.*

Comment: Are you familiar with the posting [cleveref and aliascnt: referring to ... inequalities in a smart way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258797/5001)? The [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258853/5001) -- shameless self-citation alert! -- defines a new environment called `ineq` that employs the `equation` counter (and goes on to show how to create `\cref`-based cross-references).

Comment: @Mico Yes, I'm familiar with it, but I was hoping to get some more suggestions, since your solution doesn't work well under some circumstances I'm interested in [as I described here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/667531/21685).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\crefalias` (section 6 in the manual of `cleveref`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newenvironment{inequality}
  {\crefalias{equation}{inequality}\begin{equation}}
  {\end{equation}\ignorespacesafterend}
\crefname{inequality}{ineq.}{ineqs.}
\Crefname{inequality}{Ineq.}{Ineqs.}

\begin{document}

\begin{inequality}\label{q}
x \leq y
\end{inequality}
Behold~\cref{q}.

\begin{equation}\label{r}
x = y
\end{equation}
Behold~\cref{r}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to get the same output as for equations, you need to use `\crefformat` and friends.

Comment: Thank you. A very elegant solution. However, there's a problem with it, albeit not one that can be seen under the conditions presented in my original question. I'll briefly explain the problem. If you can modify your solution to address the issue, it'll be great. If not, please tell me if I should start a separate post for it. (To be continued in the next comment.)

Comment: The problem is this. If the document's language is Hebrew (via `babel`), the `showlabels` package doesn't work with your solution. To see this, first add the following command to the preamble and recompile to display the labels: `\usepackage{showlabels}`. Then add the following two commands to the preamble to set the document's language to Hebrew: `\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSerif}`. Recompile. The labels disappear!

Comment: @EvanAad that requires a whole new question.

Comment: OK. [Here's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/667631/21685) the new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without creating a new environment, simply by cleveref:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newcounter{inequality}
\crefname{inequality}{Inequality}{Inequalities}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label[inequality]{q}
x \leq y
\end{equation}
Behold~\cref{q}. 
\end{document}
```

If you want to retain the (continous) numbering with the equations, you can use the aliascnt package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newaliascnt{inequality}{equation}
\crefname{inequality}{ineq.}{ineqs.}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label[inequality]{q}
x \leq y
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{r}
x = y
\end{equation}
Behold~\cref{q} and \cref{r}. 
\end{document}
```

**Update:**
This builds on the previous solutions, by creating indeed a new environment. The label type is overridden in the environment to inequality, so that it must not be provided.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newaliascnt{inequality}{equation}
\crefname{inequality}{ineq.}{ineqs.}
\makeatletter


\newenvironment{inequality}{
\begin{equation}
\protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
  \expandafter\cref@override@label@type%
    \cref@currentlabel\@nil{inequality}}%
}{
\end{equation}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{inequality}\label{in1}
x \leq y
\end{inequality}

\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
x = y
\end{equation}

\begin{inequality}\label{in2}
x \geq y
\end{inequality}

\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
x + 1 = y + 1
\end{equation}

Behold~\cref{in1} and \cref{eq2} and \cref{in2} and \cref{eq2}. 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This might work if I was dealing with only a handful of inequalities, but I'm dealing with a lot of inequalities. An `inequality` environment will reduce the amount of typing required, and the amount of typing errors.

Comment: Additionally, not all inequalities are going to be labelled, and I'd like to differentiate them from `equations` easily.

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/190997/21685).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've now posted an update.

Comment: The update is good. However, I'd like to wait a little before I accept your answer, so I can possibly get more suggestions. Because while your update does answer my question under the conditions presented in my question, in real life the conditions I work under are more complicated and make your answer not ideal. (If you wish, I can explain exactly how your answer fails in my real world scenario. Again, for the scenario described in my question, your update works very well.)

Comment: FYI I've described the scenario under which your solution doesn't work well in [this new post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/667631/21685).

Comment: I've decided to accept egreg's answer rather than yours, even though your answer works just as well as his, and even though you answered first, because his answer doesn't require the use of the `aliascnt` package which is complicated, difficult to understand, and error-prone.