# An equation-like environment shows the inequality number on the wrong side of the page when the document's language is Hebrew

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, babel, hebrew, alias

The following LaTeX code was saved in `~/Test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
%\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSans}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{aliascnt}
\newaliascnt{inequality}{equation}
\aliascntresetthe{inequality}

\makeatletter
\def\inequality{$$\refstepcounter{inequality}}
\def\endinequality{\eqno\hbox{\@eqnnum}$$\@ignoretrue}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq}
    1=1
\end{equation}
\begin{inequality}\label{ineq}
1\neq2
\end{inequality}
\end{document}
```

The code uses the method described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258853/21685) to create a new `equation`-like environment called `inequality`, whose counter is aliased to the counter of the `equation` environment. This trick is intended to be used in conjunction with `cleveref` cross-references, but for the purposes of this question cross-referencing is redudant, and therefore was not exercised in the MWE above.

Then the following commands were executed in the Terminal:

```
> cd ~
> lualatex Test
```

Consequently a PDF file was generated at `~/Test.pdf`. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displayed as follows. (I screenshot only the relevant part of the display.)

[image: Inequality in an English document]

As can be seen, the numbers of both the equation and the inequality appear on the right side of the text region.

The two commented LaTeX lines were now uncommented to establish Hebrew as the document's main language, and the code was recompiled. The resulting PDF file looked as follows.

[image: Inequality in a Hebrew document]

As can be seen, the number of the inequality switched sides and is now left-aligned, whereas the number of the equality remains right-aligned.

This behavior is undesirable. The inequality's number should be right-aligned to match the alignment of the equality's number. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: you want `\leqno` not `\eqno`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, I don't. I really don't. The alignment of the equation's number is good, and consistent with other environments, such as `\align`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Additionally, if I add the `leqno` class option, the inequality's number vanishes.

Comment: `\leqno` [produces what you ask for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMmbL.png)  (produced with `\leqno` after uncommenting the babel lines) Obviously as you have chosen to use tex primitives such as `$$` and `\eqno` you need to be responsble for switching sides, you can not expect babel to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is low-level (`\eqno` and `\hbox` are not really LaTeX commands). I’m not sure what’s the purpose of your definitions, but try with:

```
\newenvironment{inequality}
  {\[%
   \refstepcounter{inequality}%
   \tag{\theinequality}}
  {\]\ignorespacesafterend}
```

**Edit.** Replaced the `equation` environment by `\[`...`\]` (see comments).

Comment: To clarify to my future self: the code in Javier's answer is supposed to replace the part of my MWE between (and including) the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` commands.

Comment: Yes, it replaces that part.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've unaccepted your answer. After further tests I've realized there are some serious issues with the way your code interacts with cleverefs. I will open a new question about it.

Comment: I'm managed to resolve one of the serious issues. With your code a `\cref` to the inequality cites a wrong number. However, if you replace your `\begin{equation}` with `\[`, and your `\end{equation}` with `\]`, then `\cref` reports the correct number.

Comment: The second serious issue, which I haven't managed to resolve, is that when your code is used in an English document, `\cref` doesn't say "ineq.", it says "eq." In a Hebrew document this problem doesn't surface.

Comment: I've written [this other post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/667542/21685) to address a problem with your solution: that it fails when the document's language is NOT Hebrew.

Comment: I've accepted your answer even though it doesn't work in an English document, because working in an English document was not a requirement in my question. In a Hebrew document I prefer your solution over David Carlisle's, because when the `showlabels` package is loaded, David's solution places the label inside the equation, whereas yours places it in the margin.

Comment: Having said that, [Ulrike Fischer's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/667637/21685), posted as an answer to another question of mine, is the one I'm going to deploy in the "real world", since it works both in an English document as well as in a Hebrew one, and because it doesn't require the use of the `aliascnt` package.

Answer (score 2):

`\def`, `$$` and `\eqno` are low level tex primitves. Naturally if you cut through latex interfaces and code at that level you may need to do more work "by hand". Here changing `\eqno` to `\leqno` depending on the directionality.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSans}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{aliascnt}
\newaliascnt{inequality}{equation}
\aliascntresetthe{inequality}

\makeatletter
\def\inequality{$$\refstepcounter{inequality}}
\def\endinequality{\leqno\hbox{\@eqnnum}$$\@ignoretrue}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq}
    1=1
\end{equation}
\begin{inequality}\label{ineq}
1\neq2
\end{inequality}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a good solution. However, if I now add `\usepackage{showlabels}` (I rely on the `showlabels` package a lot in the "real world"), the braces around the inequalitie's label are turned inside out. It's not catastrophic, but it's quite annoying.

Comment: But the vertical spacing before and after the equation can be wrong (larger than the correct one).

Comment: @EvanAad well that is to be expected if you use `$$` you can not expect latex packages written last millenium to magically adapt to your definition. You are generating the issue by not using `equation` so odd to get annoyed by that

Comment: @JavierBezos sure, `$$` is not right but it is no more or less right in RTL text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't really understand the internals of the code I used. I simply copied it from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/190997/21685).

Comment: @EvanAad there is no `$$`  or `\eqno` in that link

Comment: Oops. You're right. My apologies. I meant [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258853/21685).

Comment: If you replace `$$` by `\[` and `\]`, respectively, the braces around the label face the correct direction. However, the label is then positioned inside the text region rather than in the margin where it should be.

Comment: @EvanAad `\(l)eqno` in `\[` (or `$$`) is not supported latex syntax so anything `showlabels` does with the label is accidental untested code paths and not a bug.