# The showlabels package fails for a custom equation-like environment, when the document's language is Hebrew

Tags: equations, babel, cleveref, hebrew, showlabels

In [another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/667482/21685) I asked how to create a new `equation`-like environment called `inequality` that will share `equation`'s counter. I received two good answers. However, these answers are not satisfactory under additional two conditions that I'm interested in. The conditions are:

- that the document's language be set to Hebrew via `babel`.
- that the labels be shown.

I use the `showlabels` package to show the labels, however I have no particular attachment to this package; if there's a solution to my problem that doesn't use `showlabels`, it will be just as welcome. On the other hand, the `babel` package is a hard requirement for a solution to be accepted.

Consider, for example, [egreg's answer to my other post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/667608/21685), to which I have added the `\usepackage{showlabels}` command at the end of the preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
%\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSerif}
%\babelfont{sf}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSans}
%\babelfont{tt}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeMono}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\newenvironment{inequality}
  {\crefalias{equation}{inequality}\begin{equation}}
  {\end{equation}\ignorespacesafterend}
\crefname{inequality}{ineq.}{ineqs.}
\Crefname{inequality}{Ineq.}{Ineqs.}

\usepackage{showlabels}
\begin{document}

\begin{inequality}\label{q}
x \leq y
\end{inequality}
Behold~\cref{q}.

\begin{equation}\label{r}
x = y
\end{equation}
Behold~\cref{r}.

\end{document}
```

When this code is compiled with two calls to `lualatex`, the following output is produced.

[image: egreg's solution in an English document]

If now the document's language is set to Hebrew by uncommenting the four commented lines and recompiling, the resulting output is:

[image: egreg's solution in a Hebrew document]

Note how the labels have disappeared! A similar outcome is observed with the solution given in [BotonF's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/667485/21685). (Bear in mind that Hebrew is a right-to-left language, and so the text's right-alignment is to be expected, and isn't a problem.)

Three other solutions have been considered, but none of them is adequate.

- [Mico's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258853/21685) suffers from the problem, which I described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/667531/21685), that in a Hebrew document the `inequality` environment's numbering is left aligned.
- [David's Carlisle's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/667535/21685) suffers from the problem that in a Hebrew document the label is positioned inside the equation instead of in the margin.
- [Javier Bezos' solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/667533/21685) works well in a Hebrew document, but fails in an English document, as I described [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/667542/21685) (which remains unanswered at the present time). I'd like a solution which will work well both in Hebrew documents and in English ones (as well as in bilingual documents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both `showlabels` and `showkeys` patch the `\@eqnnum` command to retrieve labels in the equation environment.

Sadly babel overwrites this command again in `luababel.def`. You could try this (but I didn't check if it works with the additional complication of cleveref):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
\usepackage{showlabels}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/bbl@eqnum/after}{%
  \ifx\SL@labelname\relax
      % do nothing
    \else
      \SL@eqntext{\SL@labelname}%
    \fi
    \global\let\SL@labelname\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}\label{r}
x = y
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works with `cleveref`. Thank you very much!

Comment: From my tests it looks like it doesn't matter where your patch is placed in the preamble: it can be the last thing in the preamble, after `showlabels`, or the first thing, before `babel`, or anywhere in between; it works regardless. Are there any placement considerations I should take into account when deploying this patch in the "real world"?